# Django: Setting up a user profile page?

Tags: django

I'm still a novice and I'm not sure how I should setup the profile page for users. The `django.contrib.auth.views.login` will redirect to a `accounts/profile` page, but how should I actually set this up?

Is it common to just define `accounts/profile` in `urls.py` and have it redirect to a template or is it a more complex pattern?

`django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template, {'template':'profile.html'})` where `profile.html` lives in `PROJECT_ROOT/templates/profile.html` and extends `base.html`?

Comment: More complete answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set up a view/url that points to accounts/profile, or you can tell Django to redirect somewhere else after login by setting the [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) param in your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some reusable apps out there for handing common profile page functionality, take a look at https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home or http://code.google.com/p/django-profile/