# Django user profile

Tags: django, django-models

When adding additional fields to a user profile, such as location, gender, employer, etc., should I be adding additional columns to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and saving it there? Or should I be creating a new table to save user profile information?

Also, when a user uploads a profile picture, should I be saving this in the same table? (Note this is not a production server, I'm just doing this on my local runserver to figure things out). Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to make a model for the user profile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbpath', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: %s' % self.user.username
```

Then configure in `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
```

Comment: Thanks, this got it working for me. But how would I access fields of User in admin.py? I'm trying to set up a ModelAdmin for UserProfile and tried accessing User fields like this: 'user__last_name'. But I get this error: 'user__last_name' is not a callable or an attribute of 'UserAdmin' or found in the model 'UserProfile'. How can I access these elements?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that OneToOne with the User is a better than ForeignKey(unique=True) approach in such case.

Comment: -1 for using ForeignKey instead of OneToOne, @Dmitry has a better answer. Also AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is a legacy setting not needed for Django 1.5+

Comment: `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is deprecated.

Comment: May I know `class UserProfile` should defined in which file? Currently, our `class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser)` defined in file `models.py`. Should `UserProfile` be placed in the same file?

Answer (score 39):

> Conceptually, OneToOneField is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object. This is the recommended way of extending User class.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

Comment: Very clean solution

Comment: It's recommended to use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of User

Answer (score 18):

Current Django is 1.9 and here are some updates to the outdated accepted answer

1. use `models.OneToOneField(User)`
2. add `related_name='profile'`
3. use `.__str__()` and `.format()` for Python 3

like so

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140)  
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile of user: {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

Using `related_name` you can access a user's profile easily, for example for `request.user`

```
request.user.profile.location
request.user.profile.gender
```

No need for additional lookups.

Comment: it working but when i login to my Django admin it show error user have no  profile. My function are work correctly but i cam't access to my admin panel

Answer (score 16):

Django provides a way of [storing additional information about users in a separate table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user) (called user profile).

Answer (score 11):

Starting with Django 1.5 you can replace the default User with your custom user object using a simple settings entry:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

For slightly more details, check this [Django documentation entry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Everyone should take note of the "auth" part. Avatars and bios should not be in the AUTH_USER_MODEL. Unless you want to integrate something like kerberos into your user authentication I would stick with django.contrib.auth. A one-to-one model with User should remain the way to do things in Django 1.5+  It seems like location, gender, employer are not valid authentication parameters and should not be added to a custom user model.

Comment: Upvoted for link to the official, (and as of now) current, docs.  I appreciate that, because this is one of those issues where it seems like the Internet's vast capacity for storing the history of once-good answers about a framework results in a confusing mish-mash of hodge-podgery.  :)

Comment: @JohnLockwood just re-updated the link so it should be good for the years to come :P

Answer (score 5):

There's a solution I found [here](http://sontek.net/blog/detail/extending-the-django-user-model). Basically you just extend the default form `UserCreationForm` but keeping the same name. It works seamlessly with the way Django's docs tell you to do `UserProfiles`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer can be updated to add signal receiver which will create the profile if it does not exist and update if it is already there.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

This https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/23/how-to-add-user-profile-to-django-admin.html post also includes how to edit, list the custom profile in admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

The current 2 top answers are outdated

> If you reference `User` directly (for example, by referring to it in a foreign key), your code will not work in projects where the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting has been changed to a different user model. [..] Instead of referring to `User` directly [..] when you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the user model, you should specify the custom model using the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="userprofile",
    )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get user profile data from user objects.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
request.user.profile
```