# Django return "Profile matching query does not exist"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some issue.
I import django User model, create new user then trying to get it profile, all what I have is "Profile matching query does not exist". Why? I just create the user.

Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
user = User.objects.create(username="stackoverflow", password="tester1234")
user.get_profile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The online documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile) suggests that get_profile()...

> Returns a site-specific profile for this user. Raises django.contrib.auth.models.SiteProfileNotAvailable if the current site doesn't allow profiles, or django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist if the user does not have a profile. For information on how to define a site-specific user profile, see the section on storing additional user information below.

Are you sure you've enabled profiles?

From your code snippet it looks like you've perhaps not created a profile which is a separate class (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile).

Answer (score 2):

You might have forgotten to set

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
```

in your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1):

also write save method in signals.py:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def save_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and also add this in app.py

```
class UserProfileConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'UserProfile'

    def ready(self):
        import UserProfile.signals
```

Answer (score 0):

Django docs define this clearly, I miss that, sorry

> Storing additional information about users
>
> If you'd like to store additional information related to your users,
>   Django provides a method to specify a site-specific related model --
>   termed a "user profile" -- for this purpose.
>
> To make use of this feature, define a model with fields for the
>   additional information you'd like to store, or additional methods
>   you'd like to have available, and also add a OneToOneField named user
>   from your model to the User model. This will ensure only one instance
>   of your model can be created for each User. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>
> class UserProfile(models.Model):
>     # This field is required.
>     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
>
>     # Other fields here
>     accepted_eula = models.BooleanField()
>     favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Dragons.")
> ```
>
> To indicate that this model is the user profile model for a given
>   site, fill in the setting AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE with a string consisting
>   of the following items, separated by a dot:
>
> The name of the application (case sensitive) in which the user profile model is defined (in other words, the name which was passed to
>   manage.py startapp to create the application).
>   The name of the model (not case sensitive) class.
>
> For example, if the profile model was a class named UserProfile and
>   was defined inside an application named accounts, the appropriate
>   setting would be:
>
> ```
> AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
> ```
>
> When a user profile model has been defined and specified in this
>   manner, each User object will have a method -- get_profile() -- which
>   returns the instance of the user profile model associated with that
>   User.
>
> The method get_profile() does not create a profile if one does not
>   exist. You need to register a handler for the User model's
>   django.db.models.signals.post_save signal and, in the handler, if
>   created is True, create the associated user profile:
>
> ## in models.py
>
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User from
>   django.db.models.signals import post_save
>
> ```
> # definition of UserProfile from above
> # ...
>
> def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
>     if created:
>         UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
>
> post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
> ```