# How to upload an image in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a new app in django environment. I want to upload image of user when he/she sign-up's in my app and i want to use the same image when he/she posts any comment in my app. So how to integrate image-uploading code into my app code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `UserProfile` as has been answered here [Django user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile) and have the ImageField in there.

Then create a `ModelForm` for the UserProfile and render it wherever you want the user to setup their profile and add a user image. The Model form will render the ImageField as a file upload field and have default handles for it. Make sure you have `MEDIA_URL` configured in your `settings.py`. You would also need `PIL` installed in your path for the image upload to work.

You can access the `UserProfile` instance for your `user` doing `user.get_profile` in your templates and as a callable elsewhere.