# How make Django's auth app use my custom model "User"

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I am very new to Django, and I am making an app that stores a lot of information about the user. But django's auth app stores only a bit of information about the user. Is there any way I can create my own model "User" and make Django's auth app use this model. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been supported since Django 1.5, and is fully covered in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Basically, you need to subclass auth.models.AbstractUser, and set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to point to your new model.

Comment: if I make a model "User", in my app,  that subclassess the auth.models.AbstractUser then will it be used the same way as the auth's User. I mean can I do something like `request.user.city`

Comment: Yes that's the whole point, as long as you set AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Answer (score 1):

You can solves your problem with `UserProfile` model. And you can store the user extra information in this with relation of onetone or ForeignKey with unique property field.

[Django user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile)

Answer (score 1):

U can multi-table  inheritance  the user model

```
from django.contrib.auth import User

class MyUser(User):
//add ur required fields
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) for in heritance.