# User and UserProfile models

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I need to create a custom User model for authentication backend. SSurfing the internet, I noticed that people create two models: UserProfile and User. So, as I understand, UserProfile contains an inheritence of standart User model and some additional fields. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6092091/4132352)
So, there is a question then: what does contain User model then? Or do I need only one model?

Answer (score 3):

No, you've misunderstood a couple of things.

Prior to Django 1.5, there was no way to replace or extend the built-in User model. So if you wanted to add extra fields, the recommended solution was to provide a UserProfile that had a one-to-one relationship with User.

Since Django 1.5, it has been possible to define your own user model and tell Django to use it in place of the built-in one. So now the recommendation is to do this rather than creating a UserProfile. That is what you should do: define your model that inherits from AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser, and point settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL to that.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that custom user inherits from User, not from AbstractUser. class MyUser(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

Comment: Well, that's just mad, since you now have two relationships from MyUser to User, inheritance and one-to-one, both of which use their own unique foreign key fields. Neither of these is needed: please don't do this.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question, but one by one in chat?

Comment: Or here. Look: I want to make an authentication backend, because I have another source of usernames and passwords( an existing table in DB). How to implement it in my backend? I've found no information about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: I'm sorry, why is the section on "Other authentication sources" at the top of that page not exactly what you are after?

Comment: I can see that, but in that article there is no explanaition, how to point to other source?

Comment: It just tells that we can do it, but no word about how to do it.

Comment: I can't see what else you could possibly need to know. Define the backend with an authenticate method that checks the username and password in your external database, and return a User object. That's literally everything you need to do.

Comment: I just can do it performing SELECT query with cursor, so that to check if such username with such password exists. But why do I need extended model then?

Comment: How to connect my table in DB with my extended user model?

Comment: " How to connect my table in DB with my extended user model? "
When you will create new model like
try to point yours db_table in class Meta of UserModel, like this:

`class CustomUser(AbstactBaseUser):
    pass
    class Meta(AbstractBaseUser.Meta):
        db_table = 'custom_user_table_name'`

Answer (score 0):

You only need one User model it's built into all  of the authentication logic built into Django.   UserProfile should be a customized table which has a foreign key relationship to the User.  Furthermore you should make sure anytime a new user object is created a userprofile is created as well.

This video does a good job explaining how to go about doing that.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLRxkStiaUg

Answer (score 0):

Basically you subclass the user model now and let your settings know you are going to use a custom model. You can read in detail about it in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

the big picture is:

Create the model that extends from user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

Let your settings module know you are going to use this model as your user model (settings.py):

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
```

When you are going to reference it in another model make sure you are pointing to this class:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

As an alternative, create an app for users and import it like you would with any other model:

```
from users.models import User
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```