# How show log out part and name of user on the top of page in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

I want to learn how use the Django authentication system.I can create group and add permission to it and create users and add them to group.

I want when user log-in, on top of the page, I can show the name of user who is loggin-in and put logout link near it like most of the real website. how can I do this? should I use user profile? if yes where and how should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `header.html` template like this:

```
<div class="header"> 
    <ul> 
        <li> Username: {{ user.username}} </li> 
        <li><a href='/logout'> Logout</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) this template in every template that you want to show `username` and `logout` link like this:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
```

And in your `views.py` you can pass `user` object to `template` like this:

```
def test(request):
user = request.user
variables = RequestContext( request,
    {
        'user': user,
    }
)
return render_to_response( 'test.html', variables )
```

Comment: Thanks.it helps me.I have one question that I create user profile in model but I don't know how use it?could you say how use it or give some useful source?

Comment: see [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile)