# Same models for different purposes in django

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to django so please bear with me. I'm in the process of creating a website and have written the authentication system for it using Django's 'User' model (which I customised). Now I'm wondering how does one use the same 'User' model for making a customised 'profile page' for a user i.e. When a user signs up he's only asked to provide his/her email and password. However, on successful login the user is to be greeted with a sort of a dashboard where he/she can upload media, follow people etc. This will require that the user model be extended with different fields.

Wouldn't this cause a database conflict?

Thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile

Comment: That solves the problem of how to add new columns. I already did that, my question asks a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I might this [link to resource](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1266) can help you, search before for a CRUD tutorial for Django.

Comment: I didn't get to the page you mentioned, could you provide a direct link?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [blank=true](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#blank) option on the additional User fields then you can create and validate a User without specifying values for those fields. You may also need to use the [null=true](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null) field, depending on how you want those blank values stored in the database.

Comment: So I should extend user model once and set the fields not required for authentication as blank=true? Or am I missing something here?