# Django - Checking if user has logged in before

Tags: django

when a user signs up, they get redirected to the homepage. If it is their first time logging in, I want to display a div, however if it is not their first time, I do not want this div to appear. Currently, I am relying on `date_joined` and`last_login` to do this check.

However this only checks dates and not the time. Therefore the div will still appear until the date has changed. I only want the div displayed once. This is when the user first logs in.

Here is my code so far:
views.py:

```
def home(request):
    context={}
    user = request.user
    if user.last_login.date() == user.date_joined.date():
        context['isFirstTime'] = 'isFirstTime'
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

template:

```
   {% if isFirstTime %}
        <div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;">

        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Does anybody know how I can alter this so it works with the current time and not the current date. This way the div is only displayed when a user first logs in. Anybody know a solution? Thank you.  Also `date_joined` and `last_login` are datetime objects stored in the database.

Comment: Both `last_login` and `date_joined` are DateTime values

Comment: @yorodm Yes, but how do I change the code so it does what I want.

Comment: @yorodm Only display the div if `last_login` is equal to `date_joined ` in terms of date and time. The current code only works for the date. How do I change it so it checks the current time for both these variables? What would the code look like?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you create a `UserProfile ` with an attribute `is_first_login` to track this? Default it = `True` and set it to `False` after their first login?

Comment: @Yellowduck Once set to False after first log in, I would want to display a div. How would I set this variable to True, therefore the div disappears after the first login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `last_login` and `date_joined`, consider creating a `UserProfile` model with an attribute `is_first_login`, you can read more about `UserProfile` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085025/django-user-profile) .

In your models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    is_first_login = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In your view:

```
def home(request):
    context={}
    user = request.user
    if user.profile.is_first_login:
        context['isFirstTime'] = 'isFirstTime'
        user.profile.is_first_login = False
        user.profile.is_first_login.save()
    else:
        pass
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks but one question. Why not just add `is_first_login` on existing user model, as I extend it using **AbstractUser** Thank you.

Comment: you absolutely can.

Comment: Ok I will go with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (user.last_login - user.date_joined).total_seconds() < 5:
    ... # do your code
    user.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
    user.save()
```

Both `last_login` and `date_joined` are DateTime instances so you need to compare them directly. But I recommend you to add some delta, like 5 seconds in example before to be sure

Comment: Ok so the div does appear. However how do I make it disappear?

Comment: As I only want to display the div when the use **first** logs in.

Comment: @PythonNinja007 well the easiest way is to update last_login. I updated the answer

Comment: One question though. I do not understand the code. I do not understand what the part within the if statement brackets does, or the bit inside the if statement itself. And also what does the value 5 do? Can you explain what all these parts of the code do? Thanks.

Comment: @PythonNinja007 the value in brackets is the result of datetime subtraction. It's a ```datetime.timedelta``` instance which has ```total_seconds``` method which returns a number of seconds between two dates. 5 here is threshold. So I say here "This two dates differ by 5 second or less"

Comment: Ah ok but I am still confused about what happens **inside** the if statement can you explain this further. I am also still a tiny bit confused about what the value **5** represents. Thank you.

Comment: @PythonNinja007 I've answered you earlier. 5 - is number of seconds. Inside of a statement I just updating user.last_login time so last_login will always be bigger than date_joined (more than 5 seconds)